# laravel remember me not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I have created 2 different login forms for admin and users in admin login form i have used attempt function i want to use remember me functionality but when i log in to the system without clicking remember me checkbox i can see in database it stores some value 
is it normal that its storing values not checking remember me token ?
this is my code for admin login

```
 if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], $request->remember)) {
    // if successful, then redirect to their intended location
    return redirect()->intended(route('admin.dashboard'));
  }
```

can someone please help me with remember me functionality in laravel

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try passing boolean value as second parameter to method attempt , or

```
if (Auth::viaRemember()) {
   //
}
```

use `viaRemember` in new laravel versions

also ,
check your config/session.php setting

```
'lifetime' => 10080,
'expire_on_close' => true,
```

just set your `expire_on_close` to `true` and Auth with `Auth::viaRemember()`

hope this is helpful

Comment: I am keep getting  `false` when i check `Auth::viaRemember()` 
and same time I am also get logged in when reopening that login window.
@Siddhantsankhe